# Match exact string without worrying about special characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a large amount of text data which here and there contain a lot of special character, and I need to validate it to other data (text) sources.

my question is: is it possible to "escape" a string in regex so that it does not consider the special characters?

example:

```
$text = "My Random St. [486] s/n 445 (don't call these guys)";
preg_match("/$text/", $other_text);
```

in the example here, there are a lot of special characters in `$text` as this is a massive amount of incoming text to be compared to a large amount of `$other_text` string, and sometimes the data actually contains regexps) so I need to use preg_match.

What I'm getting at, is there a "turn special characters off in this string" type of delimiter?

using above example:

```
$text = "My Random St. [486] s/n 445 (don't call these guys)";
preg_match("/%$text%/", $other_text);
```

Here, the `%` characters surrounding `$text` indicates that the string is to be taken "literal" as opposed as containing regex characters.

any ideas?

Comment: is this a literal example, or is that `$text` using placeholder text? Also, can you update your post to explain what you mean when you say "special character" (your example, for instance, has no special characters that I can tell, it's all plain ASCII)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called `preg_quote` - it will escape any relevant character to have a "plain, stupid" String match.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

```
$text = "My Random St. [486] s/n 445 (don't call these guys)";
preg_match("/". preg_quote($text, "/") . "/", $other_text);
```

Will exactly match the given string in other text.